# Multilayer Cryptic Clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

Each of the following lines is a classic cryptic-crossword-style clue. The solutions to each clue, taken in order, will make up a **second clue** with a letter count of **6**.

Trivial but necessary words such as the, and, or, of, and so on, are provided instead of clued.

Solve the first set and then solve the final clue!

---

> **Plus, Rome unbuilt** (4)

of an

> **Creative part of a circle containing it's older note** (8)

> **Brahma's terror has an expert** (6)

with

> **Shook hump added at cancelled beginning** (5)

> **Fired Drink** (4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned and explained by others already:

> 1. MORE (Chris Cudmore)
> 2. ARTISTIC (Deusovi)
> 3. MASTER (Chris Cudmore)
> 5. SHOT (Chris Cudmore)

Shook hump added at cancelled beginning. (5)

> **Mixed**. Cancelled = n**ixed**. If we add another hump to the "n" in "nixed," we get an "**m**" and "**mixed**." Because shaking is a typical method for mixing, shook = mixed.

Combining this with previous clues, we can piece together the final clue

> **More** of an **artistic master** with **mixed shot**. (6)

This led me to

> **Thomas**: an artistic master is an [M.A.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Arts); putting that together with the *mixed* letters of "shot" gives "Thomas", and the definition, "More", refers to [Thomas More](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_More).

Comment: I think you have the right answer, but wrong logic. A "Master of Arts", as the degree, is the "M.A." Mixed with "shot", that gives THOMAS, and "More" is the definition. (Cryptic clues have entirely separate wordplay and definition parts: they **do not interact** (except in the case of &lit clues).)

Comment: Yes. I knew "More" was the definition. I had considered the "MA" thing before I got "Thomas," and didn't think to go back to it. Good catch on that.

Comment: @Deusovi I didn't realize the word play part couldn't be word play that actually related to the meaning of the answer. I see what you're saying now. Actually, now that I think about it, I don't really think that would be word play, so yeah, you're right. Well, glad Wikipedia included the word "master," anyway, because I may have just been like "'shot' and 'more' are there but I don't think it fits." Next time, I'll be more prepared for that, I guess.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the (probably?) correct logic; feel free to roll back if necessary.

Comment: And yeah, that's how it works: the wordplay is a set of "instructions" telling you how to create the word. If it relates to the meaning of the word it's pure coincidence. (Except in a double definition clue where the wordplay is just a completely different definition.)

Comment: @Deusovi I can't remember. I typed the whole thing three times before I didn't accidentally delete it trying to go back and reference the OP (downsides of using the phone app). I may have originally thought that everything before "with" was the definition. That one took me a lot less time than the "shook" line, though. You're edit looks fine (thank you for the help). Are the definitions limited to as few words as possible, typically?

Comment: Usually, but there's no rule saying they have to be. Definitions can take up the majority of a clue, even. Pretty much anything that would work as a regular crossword clue would work as a definition for a cryptic.

Comment: Well done on that clue.  Adding the hump is a new one to me.

Comment: Just a comment: the meaning of "cancelled" in clue 4 is a word I've never heard of, and having looked it up it is only used in North America. Should there have been another tag to indicate as much, as this clue would have been almost impossible for a Brit like myself?

Answer (score 7):

> MORE - Plus = more, anagram (unbuilt) of Rome

OF
AN

> ARTISTIC -- See **@Deusovi**'s answer 
>  MASTER - Bra**ma's ter**ror has an expert (master)

WITH

> ??? 
>  SHOT - (fired a gun, took a drink)

Comment: You're good so far!

Answer (score 4):

Line four is

> `AR(TIS + TI)C` - arc is a circle part, 'tis is old form of 'it is' and ti is a solfege note ("do re mi...").

Comment: Very nice. (it's older - )

Comment: @Chris: What did your edit do? I don't see any changes.

Comment: It added a blank line.  Spoiler wasnt' working.

Comment: "solfege" - there's my previously unknown word for today :-)